# How to add variable from subdataset to report? [Jasper]

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have sub Dataset that include a calculated variable that I want to show in the report. But when dragging and dropping this variable into the report the following message appears:

> You drop an object from a subdataset to the report, this is not
>   possible.

How to overcome that?

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution which is already posted at - 
[Solution-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22035080/return-value-from-subdataset-in-ireport)

However, I am posting a set of screenshots to demonstrate the same from UI -

1. Define `var` in the main data set -
   [image]
   Note - Calculation should be set to `System`
2. Define another `variable` in the sub data set - 
   [image]
3. Select the sub data set element ( it is a table in the example) and create `Return Values` mapping - 
   [image]
4. In the report, drag and drop `variable` defined in the main data set and ensure the evaluation is set to `Report` -
   [image]

And that should do it!!

Comment: Thank you but as you can see the question is old and I am no longer can validate if this will solve the problem, still this maybe helpful for new comers.